# Find $\sin(\theta/2)$, given that $\sin \theta = -4/5$ and $\theta$ terminates in $180^\circ<\theta<270^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Sorry, I'm having trouble with this trigonometry question

> Find $\sin(\theta/2)$, given that $\sin \theta = -4/5$ and $\theta$ terminates in $180^\circ<\theta<270^\circ$.

Comment: Do you know half angle formulas?  It's just a direct application.

Comment: That's a strange choice for a variable name.

Comment: I'm guessing it was intended to be $\theta$, which produced by using `\theta`.

Comment: Why are you sorry,btw?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin ^2 \dfrac{\theta}{2} = \dfrac{1-\cos \theta}{2}$

If $\sin \theta = -4/5$ and the terminal side is in the third quadrant, *draw a reference triangle in the third quadrant*. Label the hypotenuse $5$ and the "opposite" side $-4$. You can easily solve for the adjacent side, as this is a "$3-4-5$" right triangle. Notice that the sign of the adjacent side is negative, by nature of being in the third quadrant.

Now the cosine is adjacent/hypotenuse $=-3/5$. Plug this into the half angle formula and take the positive root (why? Remember that sine is the y-coordinate of the point on the unit circle...).

Comment: So did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use $\cos x = \pm\sqrt{1- \sin^2} x$  to determine $\cos \theta$ and use $180^\circ<\theta<270^\circ$ to determine its sign.

If you divide $180^\circ<\theta<270^\circ$ by $2$, you get the range of $\theta/2$.
Can you now use $\cos (2x) = 1 -  2\sin^2 (x)$ to determine $\sin (\theta/2)$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way:
$\sin2\theta=2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}$. So $$\sin{\theta}=\sin\left(2\dfrac{{\theta}}{2}\right)=2\sin{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}=2\sin{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}}.$$

Since
$\sin{\theta}=\dfrac{-4}{5}$, thus

$$2\sin{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}}=\dfrac{-4}{5},$$
which implies

$$4\sin^2{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}\left(1-\sin^2{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}\right)=\dfrac{16}{25}.$$

Can you finish it up? It's very easy, just solve for $\sin{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}$ which will give you $\pm\dfrac{2}{\sqrt5}$ or $\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt5}$. But since $180<\theta<270$ then $90<\dfrac{\theta}{2}<135$ and so $\sin{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}$ must be $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt5}$.

Comment: sorry, is there a simpler way, cause im just lost.  this looks nothing like I was taugh

Comment: Show us how you start your working then.

Comment: I just don't know how to start.  It's all confusing to me

Comment: Okay can I know just what you have been treated under trigonometry so that I will work it that way?

Comment: We've gone over the sum and differences, double and half angle formulas, I just don't know how im suppose to use em in a question like this.  I thought I could use the half angle formula sin x/2 = +_ squareroot by 1-cosx/2  but I don't have the cosine in the question.  I do better when with charts

Comment: That is why I have solved it for you in that easier way. But anyway, you can still use this half angle formula and all you have to do is to change the $\cos{\theta}$ to $\sin{\theta}$ using the identity $\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}=1$, from which you have $\cos{\theta}=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}}$

Comment: I hope you get it this time, 'flare'

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ isn't a solution.